# get the os version of the ios device connected to the PC

Tags: java, ios, version

The application is developed in java.We need to detect the OS version of the connected IOS Device to the windows or Mac Machine. Since the code is in java, we cant use UIDevice Class. Is there any way we can detect the OS Version of the connected IOS Device.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2188

Answer (score 0):

You can get current version of ios as following code

```
NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
int ver_int = [ver intValue];
float ver_float = [ver floatValue];
```

Comment: @Kirirt Modi: Thanks for the response. But i need the code that can be used in Java since the application is being developed in java.